# blink code(escape code) has been removed?

Tags: escape-characters, ansi-term

According to [Bash tips: Colors and formatting (ANSI/VT100 Control sequences)](http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting) I attemped to active blink code in my program, But may be blink code has been eliminated. Is it true?

If is not true, Please help me to use blink code.

Comment: By the way, some of the information in the bash wiki is incorrect (reading more sources will demonstrate this).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *blink* feature depends upon the terminal (or terminal emulator).  Most terminals you will use accept the control sequences documented in ECMA-48, e.g., VT100-compatible.  The control sequence may

- cause blinking on a given terminal, or
- show as a particular color, or
- simply ignored by a given terminal

Applications usually use a terminal description (terminfo or termcap).  If the terminal description does not tell how to blink, then the application will not know either.

If your computer has `infocmp` (for terminfo), that will show the *capabilities* listed in the terminal description.  `bash` only looks for `blink` — using the termcap name, since it is a termcap application.  More generally, terminfo can also describe how to blink using `sgr` (which is not available in termcap descriptions).

For example, this is a terminfo description of `vt100`:

```
> infocmp vt100
#       Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /usr/local/ncurses/share/terminfo/v/vt100
vt100|vt100-am|dec vt100 (w/advanced video),
        am, mc5i, msgr, xenl, xon,
        cols#80, it#8, lines#24, vt#3,
        acsc=``aaffggjjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~,
        bel=^G, blink=\E[5m$<2>, bold=\E[1m$<2>,
        clear=\E[H\E[J$<50>, cr=^M, csr=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dr,
        cub=\E[%p1%dD, cub1=^H, cud=\E[%p1%dB, cud1=^J,
        cuf=\E[%p1%dC, cuf1=\E[C$<2>,
        cup=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dH$<5>, cuu=\E[%p1%dA,
        cuu1=\E[A$<2>, ed=\E[J$<50>, el=\E[K$<3>, el1=\E[1K$<3>,
        enacs=\E(B\E)0, home=\E[H, ht=^I, hts=\EH, ind=^J, ka1=\EOq,
        ka3=\EOs, kb2=\EOr, kbs=^H, kc1=\EOp, kc3=\EOn, kcub1=\EOD,
        kcud1=\EOB, kcuf1=\EOC, kcuu1=\EOA, kent=\EOM, kf0=\EOy,
        kf1=\EOP, kf10=\EOx, kf2=\EOQ, kf3=\EOR, kf4=\EOS, kf5=\EOt,
        kf6=\EOu, kf7=\EOv, kf8=\EOl, kf9=\EOw, lf1=pf1, lf2=pf2,
        lf3=pf3, lf4=pf4, mc0=\E[0i, mc4=\E[4i, mc5=\E[5i, rc=\E8,
        rev=\E[7m$<2>, ri=\EM$<5>, rmacs=^O, rmam=\E[?7l,
        rmkx=\E[?1l\E>, rmso=\E[m$<2>, rmul=\E[m$<2>,
        rs2=\E>\E[?3l\E[?4l\E[?5l\E[?7h\E[?8h, sc=\E7,
        sgr=\E[0%?%p1%p6%|%t;1%;%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p1%p3%|%t;7%;%?%p4%t;5%;m%?%p9%t\016%e\017%;$<2>,
        sgr0=\E[m\017$<2>, smacs=^N, smam=\E[?7h, smkx=\E[?1h\E=,
        smso=\E[7m$<2>, smul=\E[4m$<2>, tbc=\E[3g,
```

The corresponding termcap is

```
> infocmp -Cr vt100
#       Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /usr/local/ncurses/share/terminfo/v/vt100
vt100|vt100-am|dec vt100 (w/advanced video):\
        :5i:am:bs:ms:xn:xo:\
        :co#80:it#8:li#24:vt#3:\
        :@8=\EOM:DO=\E[%dB:K1=\EOq:K2=\EOr:K3=\EOs:K4=\EOp:K5=\EOn:\
        :LE=\E[%dD:RA=\E[?7l:RI=\E[%dC:SA=\E[?7h:UP=\E[%dA:\
        :ac=``aaffggjjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~:\
        :ae=^O:as=^N:bl=^G:cb=\E[1K:cd=\E[J:ce=\E[K:cl=\E[H\E[J:\
        :cm=\E[%i%d;%dH:cr=^M:cs=\E[%i%d;%dr:ct=\E[3g:do=^J:\
        :eA=\E(B\E)0:ho=\E[H:k0=\EOy:k1=\EOP:k2=\EOQ:k3=\EOR:\
        :k4=\EOS:k5=\EOt:k6=\EOu:k7=\EOv:k8=\EOl:k9=\EOw:k;=\EOx:\
        :kb=^H:kd=\EOB:ke=\E[?1l\E>:kl=\EOD:kr=\EOC:ks=\E[?1h\E=:\
        :ku=\EOA:l1=pf1:l2=pf2:l3=pf3:l4=pf4:le=^H:mb=\E[5m:\
        :md=\E[1m:me=\E[0m:mr=\E[7m:nd=\E[C:pf=\E[4i:po=\E[5i:\
        :ps=\E[0i:rc=\E8:rs=\E>\E[?3l\E[?4l\E[?5l\E[?7h\E[?8h:\
        :..sa=\E[0%?%p1%p6%|%t;1%;%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p1%p3%|%t;7%;%?%p4%t;5%;m%?%p9%t\016%e\017%;$<2>:\
        :sc=\E7:se=\E[m:sf=^J:so=\E[7m:sr=\EM:st=\EH:ta=^I:ue=\E[m:\
        :up=\E[A:us=\E[4m:
```

(The termcap name for `blink` is `mb`, which you can see in the description).

So... if you are not seeing *blinking* text, that could be (a) the terminal itself or (b) the terminal description.

Further reading:

- [***infocmp*** - compare or print out terminfo descriptions](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/infocmp.1m.html)
- [terminfo - terminal capability data base](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/terminfo.5.html)
- [Standard ECMA-48:
  Control Functions for Coded Character Sets](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm)

Comment: I have mb, But I don't have blink with `echo -e "\033[5mHello"`

Comment: But your terminal may not do blinking... (what terminal?)

Comment: BTW, I removed m after 5, blink turn on and goto is turn on, oh ....

Comment: But `echo -e "\033[5Hello"` would move your cursor to line 5.

Comment: Oh, Would you write me true blink text?

Comment: sorry for english language: Would you please blink text for me?

Comment: What terminal program are you using?

Comment: I tested in ptsX and ttyX

Comment: I have evidence that is inconsistent with this answer. Specifically, two different linux machines one in which blink works via perl Term::ANSIColor and another linux machine in which blink does not work. Both machines have exactly the same teminfo and termcap output. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003349/perl-termansicolor-not-working-on-raspberry-pi-console

Answer (score 5):

`printf '\033[5mHello\033[0m\n'` produces:

Blinking text in

- cool-retro-term 1.1.1
- elementary-terminal 5.3.4
- gnome-terminal 3.32.1
- konsole5 18.12.3
- mate-terminal 1.22.1
- nemo-terminal 4.0.0
- qterminal 0.14.0
- rxvt-unicode 9.22
- st 0.8.1
- terminator 1.91
- xfce4-terminal 0.8.7.4
- xterm 344
- yakuake 3.0.5
- on macOS: Terminal, and also iTerm2 if activated in Profile > Text > Text Rendering.

Highlight through a background color in

- FreeBSD 12 console
- Eterm
- on Windows: mintty (used by Cygwin), PuTTY

Highlight through a foreground color in

- emacs-terminal 5.3.4
- on Windows: TeraTerm

Reverse video in

- mrxvt

No effect in

- Linux console
- Solaris 11.4 console
- guake 0.8.8
- lilyterm 0.9.9.2
- lterm 1.5.1
- lxterminal 0.3.2
- roxterm 3.7.3
- termit 2.9.6
- on macOS: iTerm2 (unless explicitly activated)

Comment: Cygwin mintty blinks for me. Did you forget to enable the feature?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the settings are buried **deep** in the settings in your terminal emulator.

In ITerm2:

- Preferences (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>)
- Profiles
- dark (-> my current profile)
- Text
- Text Rendering
- ☑ Blinking text allowed

Answer (score 2):

Blink code doesn't work on VTE terminal such as `gnome-terminal`, `tilda`, `guake`, `terminator`, `xfce4-terminal` and so on.

You have to try with `xterm` .

Comment: Yes - this has been known for some time (see this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vte/+bug/590735) for instance.

Comment: Blinking will be supported in `VTE` 0.52 [to be released in March 2018] (`gnome-terminal` 3.28, and all other VTE-based emulators if using a recent enough VTE).

Comment: @egmont , Oh , It's new and very nice.

Comment: Blink works for me in gnome-terminal. (Nov 2021, Gnome 40.4.0, Ubuntu 21.10)

Answer (score -1):

I was looking for this from long time. I am using red hat Linux. After many expriments it is observed that echo -e "\e[5m Hello world \e[0m" will not blink on graphic mode I.e. Ctrl+alt+F7. It will work in command line mode from ctrl+alt+F1 to ctrl+alt+F6 only.

Comment: The "graphic mode" as you call it, usually (but not always) on Ctrl+Alt+F7, offers various terminal emulator applications. Some of these support blinking text, some don't.